# sudo apt-get install "anything" gives this error

Tags: apt, sudo, libreoffice

I uninstalled LibreOffice since then when I try to install something it gives me that error below :

[image: error]

Even if I follow the instructions and run

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

it gives antoher error :

[image: another]

Comment: try `sudo apt --reinstall install libreoffice`

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, we cannot copy/paste detail from your picture to check details and use it in reply to you. You also didn't provide your release.

Comment: please add the output of `apt policy openoffice-debian-menus`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `openoffice-debian-menus`:

```
sudo dpkg -P openoffice-debian-menus
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

([via](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=95150))

Comment: Fixed it. thank you a lot!